# Component Testing (A/B Testing) an exiting personalized component with Geolocation in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, ip-geolocation

I'm trying to create a A/B component test in Sitecore on a existing condition on a component, example:

A certain banner image is only displayed if a request comes from New York city, for all the other requests the image will not be displayed. Can I now create a A/B component test (new Variant) on top of this condition to display two different images randomly?

When I create the variant on the city condition I no longer have access to the default condition (no image in case of city different of New York), meaning that I cannot switch between conditions in the component menu, from that moment on I can only switch between test variants.

Before creating the variant:

[image]

After creating the variant:

[image]

Does anyone know if this configuration is possible in Sitecore (8.0 150812), or did anyone had to do something similar, and if so how was it achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is changed in more recent versions of Sitecore, (tested in Sitecore 8.1 update 2) with this version the edit variations button is directly greyed out when there is personalization rule. so not possible anymore to create personalizate variant and test variants.

Not the way to go, try page testing if you use a personalized component.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But using a page testing with personalized component, how could I make the test just for the New York condition? Thanks in advance